# Verifying Jenkins calls while testing pipeline code

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, spock, jenkins-spock

I am writing a Jenkins pipeline library, and am having some difficulties with mocking/validating an existing Jenkins pipeline step.

I am using [jenkins-spock by homeaway](https://github.com/homeaway/jenkins-spock) to unit test, but I think my problem is more Spock related.

```
import com.homeaway.devtools.jenkins.testing.JenkinsPipelineSpecification
import com.company.pipeline.providers.BuildLogProvider

class PublishBuildLogSpec extends JenkinsPipelineSpecification {
    BuildLogProvider buildLogProvider = Mock()
    PublishBuildLog publishBuildLog

    def setup () {
        publishBuildLog = new PublishBuildLog(buildLogProvider: buildLogProvider)
        explicitlyMockPipelineStep('writeFile')
    }

    def "Gets the log file contents for a specific job and build"() {
        when:
            "the call method is executed with the jobName and buildNumber parameters set"
            publishBuildLog.call("JOBNAME", "42")
        then:
            "the getBuildLog on the buildLogProvider is called with those parameters"
            1 * buildLogProvider.getBuildLog("JOBNAME", "42")
    }

    def "the contents of log file is written to the workspace"() {
        given:
            "getBuildLog returns specific contents"
            def logFileText = "Example Log File Text"
            buildLogProvider.getBuildLog(_, _) >> logFileText

        when:
            "publishBuildLog.call is executed"
            publishBuildLog.call(_, _)

        then:
            "the specific contents is passed to the writeFile step"
            1 * getPipelineMock("writeFile").call([file: _ , text: logFileText])
    }

}
```

This is my unit test.  I am attempting to say that writeFile is called with the text matching the contents of logFileText, ignoring what the other parameters are.  I have tried numerous combinations, but always seem to get the same or similar response to response of:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * getPipelineMock("writeFile").call([file: _ , text: "Example Log File Text"])   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * (explicit) getPipelineMock("writeFile").call(['file':'filename', 'text':'Example Log File Text'])
```

This is to test this class

```
import com.company.pipeline.providers.BuildLogProvider

class PublishBuildLog {

    BuildLogProvider buildLogProvider = new BuildLogProvider()

    void setBuildLogProvider(BuildLogProvider buildLogProvider) {
        this.buildLogProvider = buildLogProvider
    }

    def call(def jobName, def buildNumber) {
        def contents = buildLogProvider.getBuildLog(jobName, buildNumber)
        writeFile(file: "filename", text: contents)
    }
}
```

I am at a loss as to how to validate this call.  I have a lot of experience with Java and Junit, but I am relatively new to Spock.

How can I verify this?

Comment: From inside a class like PublishBuildLog  you can't really call a library step like writeFile. This must be failing with a 'method not found' or similar. Maybe in the context of the test that ends up being an unmatched invocation.

Answer (score 0):

For me your test passes. But there is one thing I find strange: You use jokers in a `when:` block where you should really use concrete parameters like in the first feature method:

```groovy
when: "publishBuildLog.call is executed"
publishBuildLog.call(_, _)
```

Instead you should write:

```groovy
when: "publishBuildLog.call is executed"
publishBuildLog.call("JOBNAME", "42")
```

For me this works just fine if I use this as a dummy class in order to make the code compile (because you did not provide the source code):

```groovy
class BuildLogProvider {
  def getBuildLog(def jobName, def buildNumber) {}
}
```